# NEC Definition of "Maintained Spacing" for Wire in Free Air

Tags: electrical, wire, nec

This seems like a simple question, but I cannot seem to find the answer in the 2008 NEC.

There are references to "maintaining spacing" in many sections of the code such as the following:

> **310.15.B.3.a**
>
> (a) More Than Three Current-Carrying Conductors in a Raceway or Cable.
>   Where the number of current-carrying conductors in a raceway or cable
>   exceeds three, or where single conductors or multiconductor cables are
>   installed ***without maintaining spacing*** for a continuous length longer
>   than 600 mm (24 in.) and are not installed in raceways, the allowable
>   ampacity of each conductor shall be reduced as shown in Table
>   310.15(B)(3)(a). Each current-carrying conductor of a paralleled set of conductors shall be counted as a current-carrying conductor.

For the life of me, I cannot find what "proper spacing" is for two wires run in parallel in free air. At the moment, I am most interested in the answer for NM-type wiring, but it would be good to have a reference for all types of wiring if possible.

Here is an example from the NEC for multiconductors in cable trays where I am hoping someone knows of an equivalent section that defines proper maintained spacing for free-air:

> **392.80.A.1.c**
>
> (c) Where multiconductor cables are installed in a
>   single layer in uncovered trays, with a ***maintained spacing
>   of not less than one cable diameter between cables***, the
>   ampacity shall not exceed the allowable ambient
>   temperature-corrected ampacities of multiconductor cables,
>   with not more than three insulated conductors rated 0
>   through 2000 volts in free air, in accordance with
>   310.15(C).

Comment: This is a "mike holt forum" depth of question.

Comment: [From Mike Holt Forum](http://forums.mikeholt.com/showthread.php?t=121990). "*That is the million dollar question. I just keep them from touching. Keep in mind that you can have 4- 2 wire nm cables stacked without being hurt by the derating that is necessary.*"

Comment: @Tester101 Thank you for the leg work on that. If you want to put your comment into an answer and explicitly indicate that it is not currently defined, I will accept your answer.

Comment: I would interpret that as referring to cables are run in such a way that nothing would prevent them from sitting against each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The National Electrical Code (NEC) does not define the proper spacing that should be maintained.

A similar question was asked, and answered on the [Mike Holt Forum](https://forums.mikeholt.com/threads/nec-334-80.71886/).

> That is the million dollar question. I just keep them from touching. Keep in mind that you can have 4- 2 wire nm cables stacked without being hurt by the derating that is necessary.

Answer (score -2):

Spacing for single insulated conductors in cable trays, is in art.392.80(A)(2)(c) and (d).

Comment: -1 This may not answer the question. At a minimum, the referenced code should be quoted here.